# How to simplify my CSS code using symbols?

Tags: css

i have the following code:

```
.hyperlink {
    -fx-font-size: 6px;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}

.hyperlink .glyph-icon {
    -fx-fill: #b45959;
}

.hyperlink:hover > .glyph-icon {
    -fx-fill: #b4383e;
}

.hyperlink:pressed > .glyph-icon {
    -fx-fill: #af0e0f;
}


#clearList {
    -fx-font-size: 6px;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}

#clearList .glyph-icon {
    -fx-fill: #b45959;
}

#clearList:hover > .glyph-icon {
    -fx-fill: #b4383e;
}

#clearList:pressed > .glyph-icon {
    -fx-fill: #af0e0f;
}
```

As you can see half of the code is redundant. My css's skills are really bad. Can someone show me how i can simplify that code? I mean using something like that:

```
.hyperlink, #clearlist {
}
```

I tried myself but i have a lot of errors...

Comment: What type of `errors` are occurs ?

Comment: Adding a common class to both elements would the obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
.hyperlink, #clearList {
    -fx-font-size: 6px;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}

#clearList .glyph-icon, .hyperlink .glyph-icon {
    -fx-fill: #b45959;
}


#clearList:hover > .glyph-icon, .hyperlink:hover > .glyph-icon {
    -fx-fill: #b4383e;
}


#clearList:pressed > .glyph-icon, .hyperlink:pressed > .glyph-icon {
    -fx-fill: #af0e0f;
}
```